# PXE server - ubuntu setting username/password later - is it possible?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, user-management, pxe-boot, chroot

so I am writing a program in mainly C/C++, though I think this question fits under server fault as it is related to the Linux distro Ubuntu.

So what I am looking for is a way (possibly hackerish-way) to install Ubuntu 12.04 (or later), BUT without setting username/password upon installation. I know, if you have used Windows Server 2008/2012 with Active Directory that you can specify that users are to change/set password upon next boot-up, though I am unsure as to how this could be done in a Linux environment.

Basically what is the goal here; `normal installation (Ubuntu)` -> `Boot once, tweaking` -> `next bootup set username/password`. All but the last part is done by me and the program that I am making, at ease for the users.

Now I have though about perhaps deleting/modifying files such as passwd, though this would not be sufficient. While a bit off-topic I think this part is also relevant, the program basically sets up files/directories with correct permissions and modifies conf files accordingly.

For Ubuntu 12.X++ (actual OS files being served over TFTP/NFS) then the user should be *prompted* for a `username/password` once as if they were doing a clean install of the OS.

Is this at all possible or would I have to set a default username/password and tell users to manually delete/setup their own user/password by themselves? This is what I have done for now, though I would prefer another way to do this.

Other information: this is being done on *Ubuntu Server*, possibility to `chroot` and `mount` filesystems to make changes are possible.

Hopefully nobody misunderstood me, I look forward to answers.

-- Dusz

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing something similar is:

- PXE/TFTP to install the base OS (kickstart or preseed according to your OS specific needs)
- puppet to configure the OS to match my policy
- LDAP/Kerberos to provide authentication/authorization (I am using [freeIPA](http://www.freeipa.org))
- When creating an account, the password is set to be renew upon first login (similar to `chage -d0 $USER`)
- polyinstantiation of `/home` and `/tmp` using `pam_namespace(8)`

This way, I can provide accounts centrally configured, user's home directories are only created on demand and users are forced to change their passwords on activation of their accounts.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion, though would this be _prompting_ users of program (admins, setting up PXE server) for a username/password for their Ubuntu booting option? My goal is not to massively manage a lot of users, but rather to create a functioning program that serves as a helping finger in the setup. This is why a promt for username/password once (remember my program is serving _hopefully_ a clean install without username/password) so that all the admin has to do is boot once to setup as he wishes.

Comment: It is not clear if what you want is to password-protect entries in a PXE based menu, if that is the case, check [here](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/PXELINUX), there are examples of such a setup